# Calling another JavaScript method in a class in a hybrid Cordova/Android app

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, this, instance

I am in the process of tidying up a rather large hybrid Cordova/Android app.  One of the things I am doing is reducing the size of the initial DOM tree that has to be constructed at startup by hiving off bits that are not immediately required into a "template" folder from which I then load them on demand.  For the purpose I have defined a `Loader` class as shown below

```
class Loader
{
 constructor()
 {
  this.prior = null;
  this.current = null;
 }

 loadPageTemplate(page)
 {
  this.prior = this.current;
  this.current = page;   
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function(){this.pageTemplateLoaded(xhr.responseText);};
  xhr.onerror = function(){alert(`${this.current} failed`);};
  xhr.open('GET',`tpl/${page}.es6`);
  xhr.send(null);
 }

 pageTemplateLoaded(content)
 {
  this.blankPage();
  if (this.prior) delete(this.prior);
  eval(content);
 }

 displayPage(newPage){document.getElementById('page').appendChild(newPage);}

 blankPage()
 {
  let page = document.getElementById('page');
  while (page.firstChild) page.removeChild(page.firstChild);    
 }
}

var _hold = {loader:new Loader()};
```

I ensure that the Loader script is the very first thing seen in the `<head>` section of the `index.html` file that is loaded by Cordova.  This is failing because the WebView in the Cordova app throws up complaints along the lines of

> this.pageTemplateLoaded is not defined.

I am a relative beginner when it comes to using JavaScript classes in this way so I suspect I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to delete this question but decided to leave it in with an answer for the benefit for anyone doing something along similar lines.

The key here is to appreciate what exactly the Loader class is being used for - merely to serve as a handy repository for a few utility functions.  That being the case what we need to do is to define the methods as being static and then reference them via the Loader prototype without ever instantiating it.  Here is my modified code which works

```
class Loader
{

 static loadPageTemplate(page)
 {
  _hold.prior = _hold.current;   
  _hold.current = page;   
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function(){Loader.pageTemplateLoaded(xhr.responseText);};
  xhr.onerror = function(){alert(`${_hold.current} failed`);};
  xhr.open('GET',`tpl/${page}.es6`);
  xhr.send(null);
 }

 static pageTemplateLoaded(content)
 {
  Loader.blankPage();
  eval(content);
 }

 static displayPage(newPage){document.getElementById('page').appendChild(newPage);}

 static blankPage()
 {
  let page = document.getElementById('page');
  while (page.firstChild) page.removeChild(page.firstChild); 
  if (_hold.prior) delete(_hold.prior);
 }
}

var _hold = {current:null};
```

Points to note

- With this way of doing things you can no longer have and access `instance variables`.  I have gotten around the problem by assigning `current` and `prior` to my global `_hold` object.
- For some reason 'this.pageTemplateLoaded' still failed for me.  However, `Loader.pageTempateLoaded` worked.

A very useful article to read up when undertaking something like this is [this one on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).  A sentence in that article that is worth highlighting here

> The static keyword defines a static method for a class. Static methods are called without instantiating their class and cannot be called through a class instance. Static methods are often used to create utility functions for an application.

It is also worth noting that

> With this way of doing things there is no need to create an instance of the Loader class - it would do nothing useful even if you were to do so.